# Проблема при запуске программы в режиме Debug

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Запускаю программу в режиме отладки. Программа выполняется, но в консоли надпись красным цветом:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить?

Comment: Это нормально. И ещё пару слов, чтобы комментарий можно было оставить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело было в неправильных строчках в pom.xml

```
<properties>
<maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<source>12</source>
<target>12</target>
</properties>
....
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.8.1</version>
<configuration>
<source>12</source>
<target>12</target>
<testSource>12</testSource>
<testTarget>12</testTarget>
<showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
<showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
</configuration>
```

Comment: А что там было неправильным? Вы в вопросе не pom.xml вообще не указали.

Comment: Это был мой первый вопрос здесь. Некорректно его задал.

Comment: Не беда, исправте его, есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/996510/edit).